# Filtering data using ajax observefield

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I ve tried to  implemented filtering data (list base on selected category) using dropdown with observefield and ajax pagination. I use session to remember selected category in order to keep pagination.

Here is my code (Cakephp 1.2)

In view :

```
echo $form->select('Category.id', $categories, null, array('id' => 'categories'),'Filter by Categories')
echo $ajax->observeField('categories' ,array('url' =>'update_category','update' => 'collectionDiv'));
```

In Controller:

```
if(!empty($this->data['Category']['id'])) 
{ 
    $cat_id=$this->data['Category']['id'];
    $filters=array('Collection.category_id' => $cat_id); 
    $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection', $filters));
    $this->Session->write($this->name.'.$cat_id', $category_id);
}
else
{
    $cat_id=$this->Session->read($this->name.'.cat_id');
    $filters=array('Collection.category_id' => $cat_id);
    $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection'));
}
```

The filter work as I wanted but the problem is when I select empty value('Filter by Category) it still remember last category session so I can't back to the default list (All record list without filter).

I've tried to make some condition but still not success. Is there another way? Please I appreciate your help. thank

hermawan

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but it looks to me like it might be worth changing:

```
else
{
    $cat_id=$this->Session->read($this->name.'.cat_id');
    $filters=array('Collection.category_id' => $cat_id);
    $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection'));
}
```

to:

```
else
{
    $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection',array()));
}
```

In effect your code appears to be doing this anyway. Check what the URL is at the top of the browser window after it has returned. Does it still contain pagination directives from the previous query?

You might want to review http://book.cakephp.org/view/167/AJAX-Pagination and make sure you've 'ticked all the boxes'.

Comment: thank for answer. I ve tried your advise but still don't work. Lets say I pick up 'Painting Category', then the DIV change the content as I want, but if click the page number the DIV will content whole data not only 'Painting Category'.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the ajax pagination isn't set up correctly, although I'm beginning to think that it may be a limitation of pagination. I recall having a similar problem when I altered the original query like this - it doesn't follow through on subsequent pages. I solved it by writing a custom paginate method on the appropriate model. Pagination is good at taking a query, paginating and column sorting the results. Beyond this it needs help.

Comment: Thank Leo, The pagination is set correctly. The problem  is, we should differ where request from is? When ajax observefield it will check category "id", but if Ajax pagination it should remember the category. I observe when ajax come from pagination, $this->passedArgs will return the page number, but empty when trigerred by Ajax observefiled. I explain my solution. Thank for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I got it, It work as I hope now. I my self explain the condition and solution. 
When I select category from combobox, then it render the page the code is :

```
If ($this->data['Category']['id']) {
  $cat_id=$this->data['Category']['id'];
  $this->Session->write($this->name.'.category_id', $category_id);
  // I will use this session next when I click page number
  $filters=array('Collection.art_type_id' => $category_id); 
  $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection', $filters));

}else{
//if clik page number, next or whatever, $this->data['Category']['id'] will empty so 
// use session to remember the category so the page will display next page or prev 
// page with the proper category, But the problem is, when I set category fillter to
// "All Category" it will dislpay last category taked from the session. To prevent it 
// I used $this->passedArgs['page']. When I clik the page paginator it will return 
// current number page, but it will be empty if we click dropdown. 

    if (!empty($this->passedArgs['page']) {
       $cat_id=$this->Session->read($this->name.'.category_id');
       $filters=array('Collection.category_id' => $cat_id);
       $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection',$filters));
    }else{
       $this->set('collections', $this->paginate('Collection'));
  }
}
```

From this case, I think that observefield will not send passedArg as we get from url such from ajax link or html->link. I hope this will usefull to anybody